# protobuf-net protogen generate c# classes and corresponding interfaces from proto files

Tags: protobuf-net, protogen

I am trying to write unit tests for my application and would like to have my proto-classes implement interfaces.
Preferably they would be generated together with the c# classes, but I can not find a way of doing this.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protogen tool writes standard partial-class definitions. This makes it easy to add interfaces in a second class file:

```
namespace Foo {
    partial class Bar : IWhatever {...}
}
```

Comment: Thank you one part down. Do you know if there is a way of generating them at the same time as the c#-classes. So that generating the classes will generate Interfaces as well? I am currently generating the c#-classes during pre-build and would like to get the interfaces generated at the same time.